# EF Core unique composite

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 7 with a SQL Server database.

[EDIT] The original version of this post assumed that I want to use a composite index with some sort of constraint to solve my problem. I'm not a DB expert and I'm fuzzy on the overlapping concepts of indexes, constraints, and filters. I have rewritten the question to remove the appearance that I'm looking for a solution that involves an index.

**The short version:** I have an Entity (mapped to a table via EF) that contains 2 properties (2 table rows):

```
public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
public bool IsCurrent { get; set; }
```

**Many rows can have the same `ItemId` value, but at most 1 row can contain a particular `ItemId` value and `IsCurrent == true`. How can I enforce this constraint?**

I would prefer to do this in a DB-agnostic way, but I assume I can't do this without some EF feature that knows my underlying database is SQL Server...

**The long version**

I have some tables that store medical records of various types (patient symptoms, diagnoses, treatment plans, etc.). I have a requirement to retain medical records forever, so if a doctor changes a diagnosis (for example, by adding a comment) or a treatment (by changing the dose or frequency of a medicine) I need to entomb the old version of the record (without the comment or with the old dose or frequency) and create a new medical record with the updated information.

I've created a scheme that uses a GUID `ItemId` property to identify a particular medical record (for example, a particular treatment). If the doctor changes the details of the treatment, then I create a new record with that same GUID to represent the new (current) version of that medical record. To make it easy to fetch the current version of medical records I include an `IsCurrent` property that is `true` only for the most recent generation of the medical record with that GUID identifier.

So, to reiterate, my database may contain multiple rows with the same GUID `ItemId` (representing different generations of the same medical record), but at most one row will contain a `true` value for `IsCurrent`. (It's possible that a medical record was created in error, in which case no version of that record will be "current".)

Here is a simplified example of a medical record entity, with `IsCurrent` and `ItemId` properties as described above:

```
public class Treatment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Drug { get; set; }
    public string Dose { get; set; }

    public bool IsCurrent { get; set; }
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
}
```

For performance, I've created a composite index over `IsCurrent` and `ItemId`:

```
e.HasIndex(x => new { x.ItemId, x.IsCurrent });
```

I want to enforce additional behavior that at most one row with a particular GUID `ItemId` value can contain an `IsCurrent` value of `true`.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to achieve with the index, apart from the constraint, and why a solution with Filter is not optimal?

Comment: Using a filtered unique index is the standard solution, I don't understand why it wouldn't work here. But to be honest it sounds like what you *really* need is a Temporal Table (SCD2).

Comment: @JineappleAra Sorry, I made an incorrect assumption that the solution to my **constraint** question involved a composite index. I *do* have that composite index, since my code needs to query the DB to find the one record with a particular `ItemId` and `IsCurrent == true`. But that doesn't mean that the constraint that only one record can match this criterion needs to involve that composite index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two indexes, one for performance and another one for the constraint.

The performance index is just that you have defined on your question.

The constraint index looks like this:

```cs
e
.HasIndex(x => new { x.ItemId, x.IsCurrent })
.HasFilter("[IsCurrent] = 1")          //<-- The magic is here
.HasDatabaseName("my_idx_constraint")  //<-- [Optional] 
.IsUnique();                           //<-- Only one item with isCurrent=1
```

Quoting [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations#index-filter) documentation:

> Some relational databases allow you to specify a filtered or partial index. This allows you to index only a subset of a column's values, reducing the index's size and improving both performance and disk space usage.

Disclaimer: This answer can't be applied to some relational databases.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I read the short version after post the answer. Now I see that `Filter` is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused by your comment that `Filter` is not what I'm looking for. To my non-expert eyes, the constraint index given in this answer is exactly what I'm looking for. (Off-topic question: How do I "@" mention a person whose name has a space in it? I wanted to address this question to dani herrera, but typing "@d" doesn't offer me "@dani herrera" as an "at mention"...)

Comment: Awesome, glad to help. You can't mention if no one else comments.

Comment: Huh. Who woulda thunk it? I've long wondered why sometimes I can @mention someone and sometimes I can't.